# Android studio 3.0.1 - opening avd manager without opening android studio?

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Is there any way to open the AVD Manager without opening the Android Studio? I've got the 3.0.1 version and I only need to use the AVD Manager for React Native purpose. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if it's just starting an emulator you can do: /path/to/sdk/tools/emulator.exe -avd "name_of_emulator"... I am also interested in why did they forcibly merged AVD/SDK into android studio -.- ..but in the meantime that's what I am doing to start an emulator

Comment: Ok thank you mate!!